# How to get a column from a text file in csv format using awk?

Tags: shell, csv, scripting

My text file is like

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
```

As this file is generated dynamically, there can me n number of rows

I want to convert this to csv format.

like this :

```
0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use `tr`:

```
cat file.txt | tr "\n" ","
```

But if you insist on `awk`, here you go:

```
awk '{printf "%s,",$0};' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Blender's answer works fine, but if you want to remove the last `,` and of course, use only *awk*, here is a way to do it:

```
awk '{printf "%s,",$0};' file.txt | awk '{print substr($0, 0, length($0)-1)}'
```

Here's an example of how to do the same using *sed*:

```
sed ':q;N;s/\n/,/;t q' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

echo `cat file | sed -e s/" "/","/g`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a column from a  text file (with several columns separated by comma)
you can go for

```
awk -F"," '{print $2,$3,$5.}' yourfile.csv
```

extracting second, third and fifth columns.